# How can I append the output of a checkbox to the input of a form query for a database search?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm teaching myself ruby on rails and getting into all sorts of tangled up shenanigans. I've attached snippets of my MVC down below - I want to have a search bar for a database of pet foods with four entries at this point: two text inputs for ingredients the user WANTS and DOESNT want, and then two sub-menus of checkboxes of frequently WANTED or UNWANTED ingredients.

My text input searches are working (despite messy model string processing code), but I can't figure out how to use a form_with or collections_check_box to be able to append a checked Frequently-unwanted-thing to the :ingredientsno parameter. All I can seem to do is to duplicate the parameter in the HTML link as "...ingredientsno=agar&ingredientsno=&..." -- when I use a hash form, I end up getting a jumbled URL that adds in a bunch of stuff for EACH entry in the hash regardless of if it's checked, which is also not what I want.

Do I need to make a new parameter or property for the checkboxes? Any tips?

Controller:

```
def index

@products=Product.where(nil)

@common_unwanted={'agar','carrageenan','by-product'}

@product_search = Product.search_ingredients(params[:ingredientsyes],params[:ingredientsno]).all
```

Model:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
    scope :filter_by_ingredientyes, -> (ing) {where('ingredients ILIKE all(array[?])', "#{ing}%")}
    scope :filter_by_ingredientno, -> (ing) {where.not('ingredients ILIKE all(array[?])', "#{ing}%")}


    def self.search_ingredients(wantstr,nowantstr)
        if wantstr || nowantstr
            splitstr  = wantstr.downcase.split(/\s*,\s*/)
            .map { |s| s.gsub(/[_%]/, '%' => '\\%', '_' => '\\_') }
            .map { |s| '%' + s + '%' }
            splitstr_excl  = nowantstr.downcase.split(/\s*,\s*/)
            .map { |s| s.gsub(/[_%]/, '%' => '\\%', '_' => '\\_') }
            .map { |s| '%' + s + '%' }
            puts"test1" 
            puts splitstr.length
            puts"test2"
            puts splitstr_excl.length
            if splitstr.length>=1 && splitstr_excl.length>=1
                incl_results = Product.where('ingredients ILIKE all(array[?])', splitstr)
                results=incl_results.where.not('ingredients ILIKE all(array[?])', splitstr_excl)
            elsif splitstr.length>=1
                results = Product.where('ingredients ILIKE all(array[?])', splitstr)
            elsif splitstr_excl.length>=1
                incl_results = Product.where.not('ingredients ILIKE all(array[?])', splitstr_excl)
                incl_results
            else
                self.all
            end
            #findbool=Product.where('ingredients ILIKE ?', '%'+want+ '%')
            
            #findbool=Product.where('ingredients ILIKE ?', '%'+want+ '%')
        else
            self.all
        end
    end
```

View:

```
<h3> Search by ingredient: </h3>
<%= form_with(model: @product, method: :get) do |form| %>
  <%= form.label :query, "Contains:" %>
  <%= form.text_field :ingredientsyes, value: params[:ingredientsyes] %>
  <%= form.label :query, "Contains no:" %>
<table>
    
  <%= form.text_field :ingredientsno, value: params[:ingredientsno] %>
  <br>
    <%= form.submit "Search" %>
  <% end %>


  <p> Searching for (<%= params[:ingredientsyes] %>) and no (<%= params[:ingredientsno] %>)

<%= form_with(model: @product, method: :get) do |form| %>
  <%= form.submit "Reset" %>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: The elephant in the room here is really that your modeling is completely off. In no way is storing ingredients on the recipies table a good idea since it violates 1-nf.  Create separate `ingredients` and `recipe_ingredients` tables. Then you really should consider using an ajax autocomplete to look up a single ingredient by name at a time instead of this string parsing monstrosity. That will give a much better user experience and have a much lower complexity.

Comment: Thanks max! I'm really new to RoR so this is helpful in getting me to go in my next direction.